# VBA - 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error only showing up when exporting to excel with lots of data

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have been getting this strange behaviour from my Access VBA code recently and I cannot figure out why this error is happening.

I am trying to export data from the database to an Excel file. I manipulate some cells and ranges (mostly inserting information, but sometimes merging cells, inserting new rows, etc.), however, I keep getting this error:

> 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

on this line:

```
xlApp.Cells(currentRowPointer, 8) = rs_vendorNPO("Vendor_Name")
```

Now, this line is called dozens of times, since I'm looping through a multiple recordsets and this line is inside the loop. It consistently fails when `currentRowPointer = 91`. So, to see the values of the variables when the `currentRowPointer` is 91, I added this above:

```
If currentRowPointer = 91 Then
    Stop
End If
xlApp.Cells(currentRowPointer, 8) = rs_vendorNPO("Vendor_Name")
```

`Stop` will basically add a dynamic breakpoint. So, it stopped when `currentRowPointer = 91`, and all the values seemed to be okay. I clicked run again. This time, it didn't fail on `91`, it failed on `114`. Everytime I did this, it failed on 114. So I added this to the if statement:

```
If currentRowPointer = 91 Or currentRowPointer = 114 Then
    Stop
End If
xlApp.Cells(currentRowPointer, 8) = rs_vendorNPO("Vendor_Name")
```

Sure enough, it ran just fine. To see if it did have anything to do with that iteration, I changed the if statement to this:

```
If currentRowPointer = 87 Or currentRowPointer = 114 Then
    Stop
End If
```

just to see what will happen. After the first breakpoint on `87`, it didn't fail on `114`, it failed on `111`. The next time I ran it, it failed on `112`.

This made it clear that it has nothing to do with that iteration, and is something internal with Access.

As one final test, I put a breakpoint on that line (and remove the if statement with the `Stop` call). I stepped through the entire flow, and there was no error.

---

**Questions:**

What could be causing this issue? The same lines are being called over and over again, but only after a while it seems to fail. Similarly, the issue doesn't arise when the data I'm exporting to excel is small, and has a quick run time.

This leads me to believe it's some sort of memory issue? If so, what can I do to debug this/make sure it doesn't happen?

Here is where I open the file:

```
Public xlApp As Excel.Application
Public wb As Excel.Workbook

Private Function openSpendReport(templatePath As String, filePath As String, JobID As String)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    'make a copy, file must be closed
    FileCopy templatePath, filePath
    
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    xlApp.Sheets("Summary Template").Select

Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    If Err.Number = 70 Then
        MsgBox "Close the file before running the report"
    Else
        MsgBox (Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description)
    End If

    End

End Function
```

Here is the function where the error occurs (I added a line of = signs to highlight it):

```
Private Sub getVendorNonPO(JobID As Variant)

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim rs_vendorNPO As DAO.Recordset

    sql = "<sql_statement>"
    
    Set rs_vendorNPO = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)
    If Not rs_vendorNPO.EOF Then
        Do Until rs_vendorNPO.EOF
            'add a row if necessary
            If (poRowsCount >= 8) Then
                If (cellsMerged = 0) Then
                    xlApp.Range("A" & poLineRow & ":" & "C" & currentRowPointer + 1).UnMerge 'unmerge cells
                    xlApp.Range("D" & poLineRow & ":" & "F" & currentRowPointer + 1).UnMerge
                    xlApp.Range("G" & poLineRow & ":" & "G" & currentRowPointer + 1).UnMerge
                    cellsMerged = 1
                End If

                Dim rng As Range
                Set rng = xlApp.Range("A" & currentRowPointer)

                xlApp.Rows(rng.Row).Copy
                xlApp.Rows(rng.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown

                Debug.Print ("copying cells and shifting copied cells down")
                
                ' keep track of the added rows
                poRowsAdded = poRowsAdded + 1
            End If
            
            Debug.Print ("in with 1")
            Debug.Print ("current row pointer: " & currentRowPointer)
            Debug.Print ("vendor name" & rs_vendorNPO("vendor_name"))

            ' ==========================================================================================================
            ' Issue is here
            ' ==========================================================================================================
            xlApp.Worksheets("Summary Template").Cells(currentRowPointer, 8) = rs_vendorNPO("Vendor_Name")
            Debug.Print ("in with 2")
            xlApp.Cells(currentRowPointer, 8) = rs_vendorNPO("Vendor_Name")
            xlApp.Cells(currentRowPointer, 12) = rs_vendorNPO("InvoiceNum")
            xlApp.Cells(currentRowPointer, 13) = rs_vendorNPO("InvoiceDate")
            xlApp.Cells(currentRowPointer, 14) = rs_vendorNPO("LineAmountConverted")
            xlApp.Cells(currentRowPointer, 10) = rs_vendorNPO("InvoiceDate")
            xlApp.Cells(currentRowPointer, 11) = rs_vendorNPO("LineAmountConverted")
            
            If Not IsNull(rs_vendorNPO("ProofOfPayment")) Then
                xlApp.Cells(currentRowPointer, "O") = rs_vendorNPO("ProofOfPayment")
            End If
            
            currentRowPointer = currentRowPointer + 1
            poRowsCount = poRowsCount + 1
            rs_vendorNPO.MoveNext
        Loop
        rs_vendorNPO.Close
        Set rs_vendorNPO = Nothing
    End If

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    MsgBox (Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & ". " & Err.Source)
    wb.Save
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    End

End Sub
```

Here is the output of some of the debug statements (with sensitive info removed):

```
...
in with 1
current row pointer: 90
vendor name_____
in with 2
copying cells and shifting copied cells down
in with 1
current row pointer: 91
vendor name_____
```

The debug statements began at 83. They all happened in the same loop, so I'm just showing the last couple. You can see it gets to the vendor name and fails immediately after.

Comment: Just an idea: Here you read and assign by using the default properties: `xlApp.Cells(currentRowPointer, 8) = rs_vendorNPO("Vendor_Name")`. Maybe you should explicitely use the properties you need, like `xlApp.Cells(currentRowPointer, 8).Range.Text = rs_vendorNPO("Vendor_Name").Value`. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Excel objects from outside (e.g. Access), it is best to always and strictly follow the hierarchy of the objects, which is:

```
Application -> Workbook -> Worksheet -> .Cells, .Range, ...
```

I'm not sure this will solve your problem, but chances are good IMHO.
So you should do:

```
Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet   ' or Public, if you really need

Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
Set sh = wb.Worksheets("Summary Template")
' The following is not necessary for the code to work, only if you want to watch what happens
sh.Select
```

and then change everything where you have `xlApp` to the correct references:

```
xlApp.Range    =>    sh.Range
xlApp.Rows     =>    sh.Rows
xlApp.Cells    =>    sh.Cells
xlApp.Worksheets("Summary Template").Cells    =>    sh.Cells
```

Comment: I was actually using the worksheet to reference all the rows/cells earlier. I switched it back and I'm still getting the same errors. So, every 20 iterations in the loop or so, I added `xlApp.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))` and it seems to be working. Would really love for this issue to be identified/fixed though.

Comment: So you mean the problem comes 'by iteration only' and not because of values (for example in cells) during iteration?